# Uber -- do you get rewards points when adding funds?

Tags: loyalty-programs, uber

I've been using Uber Rewards for a while now, and have just noticed that Uber offers discounts if I pre-charge my account (e.g., I can buy $100, which never expires, for $95).

My question is how do this work with the Uber rewards?

- Do I get points for the added funds?
- Do I get the points when paying (which is in advance) or when using the funds?

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.uber.com/legal/rewards-program/benefits-terms/us-en/ points are not earned on upfront purchases of Uber cash, credit, or ride passes.